# Sitecore.Courier PowerShell Installation error

Tags: installation, powershell, docker

I'm trying to install the "Sitecore XP 9.3.0 and SXA 9.3.0 Demo – Habitat Home" by following the blog from Viet Hoang.
https://buoctrenmay.com/2019/12/23/sitecore-xp-9-3-0-and-sxa-9-3-0-demo-habitat-home-setup-guide/?fbclid=IwAR1rsy_-dhPUWALMnhgv7uu-PoZwCXWWxDGDGuEZi-LvvffKj9JGwmXhpo4

Step two PowerShell instruction is failing.

```
Install-Module -Name Sitecore.Courier
```

I'm getting this error below when I run this instruction on PowerShell.

```
WARNING: Unable to resolve package source 'https://www.myget.org/F/guadzilah/api/v2'.
```

Does anybody has an idea of what the issue is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did find another command that solved the problem. You need to have "Chocolatey" installed.

**Command:**

> choco install sitecore-courier

**More Info is on these links:**
https://chocolatey.org/install
https://chocolatey.org/packages/sitecore-courier